# mod_proxy_wstunnel - Mac OS X 10.11.6, Apache 2.4.18

Tags: macos, apache, websocket, macos-sierra, osx-server

I've been trying unsuccessfully for a few days to setup a reverse proxy to a localhost websocket url.

```
ProxyPass /chat/stream/ wss://localhost:8000/chat/stream/
ProxyPassReverse /chat/stream/ wss://localhost:8000/chat/stream/
```

I get an error in the apache error_log that reads:

> No protocol handler was valid for the URL /chat/stream/. If you are
>   using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are
>   included in the configuration using LoadModule.

I have read countless pages via google of people using this method so I wonder if there is some issue in our setup/install of Apache that ships with Server.app 5.2?

I have all the standard modules loaded in httpd_server_app.conf

mod_proxy
mod_proxy_wstunnel
mod_proxy_http
...

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks

Adam

Comment: What happens if you replace `wss://` by `http://` ?

Comment: Using http works however the web app needs to connect over wss (web sockets?) - the client receives a  200 response and the handshake fails. If I use the web app on the server directly via localhost:8000 the app works fine.

Comment: Did you load mod_proxy_wstunnel with `sudo a2enmod mod_proxy_wstunnel` ?

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X - from what I understand the mod_proxy_wstunnel module is loaded in the httpd_server_app.conf file - along with mod proxy

Comment: If the module is correctly loaded you should see it in the output of `sudo apache2ctl -M`

Comment: Yes it looks to be loaded along with the proxy module: proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)

Comment: LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so

Comment: some more info from the error log:

Answer (score 2):

In case someone finds themselves in a similar situation here is how I got ​Web​Socket connections working via Apache​ in MacOS Server 5.2​.
And the solution ​i​s simple.

### The short version:​

​I use MacOS Server 5.2 (ships with Apache 2.4.23) to run a python Django application via the `mod_wsgi` module.

I had been trying to setup `proxypass` and `wstunnel`​ in MacOS 10.12 & Server 5.2 to handle websocket connections via an ASGI interface server called Daphne running on `localhost` on port `8001`.​

I wanted to reverse proxy any WebSocket connection to `wss://myapp.local/chat/stream/` to `ws://localhost:8001/chat/stream/`

​From what I had read on all the forums and mailing lists that I had scoured was to simply make some `proxypass` definitions in the appropriate virtual host and make sure that the `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_wstunnel` modules were loaded and it would work.

Long story short - from what I understand all ​of ​this trouble came down to MacOS Server 5 and one major change:

> "A single instance of httpd runs as a reverse proxy, called the Service Proxy, and several additional instances of httpd run behind that proxy to support specific HTTP-based services, including an instance for the Websites service."

All I need​ed​ to do​ to proxy the websocket connection​ was the following:

in: `/Library/Server/Web/Config/Proxy/apache_serviceproxy.conf`

​Add (around `line 297` (in the section about user websites, webdav):

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8001/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8001/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:8001%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

​I then kicked over the service proxy:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w  /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.serviceproxy.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.serviceproxy.plist
```

​And the web socket connections ​were instantly working!

### The long version:​

For many weeks I have been trying to get WebSocket connections functioning with Apache and Andrew Godwin's Django Channels project in an app I am developing.

Django Channels is

> "a project to make Django able to handle more than just plain HTTP requests, including WebSockets and HTTP2, as well as the ability to run code after a response has been sent for things like thumbnailing or background calculation."

My interest in Django Channels came from my requirement of a chat system in my webapp. After watching a several of Andrew's demos on youtube and having read through the docs and eventually installing Andrew's demo django channels project I figured I would be able to get this working in production on our MacOS Server.

The current release of MacOS 10.12 and Server 5.2 ships with Apache 2.4.23. This comes with the necessary mod_proxy_wstunnel module to be able to proxy WebSocket connections (`ws://` and secure `wss://`) in Apache and is already loaded in the server config file:

```
/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf
```

Daphne is Andrew's ASGI interface server that supports WebSockets & long-poll HTTP requests. WSGI does not.

With Daphne running on localhost on a port that MacOS isn't occupying (I went with `8001`), the idea was to get Apache to reverse proxy certain requests to Daphne.

Daphne can be run on a specified port (`8001` in this example) like so (`-v2` for more verbosity):

```
daphne -p 8001 yourapp.asgi:channel_layer -v2
```

I wanted Daphne to handle only the web socket connections (as I use currently depend on some apache modules for serving media such as `mod_xsendfile`). In my case the `websocket` connection was via `/chat/stream/` based on Andrew's demo project.

From what I had read in MacOS Server's implementation of Apache the idea is to declare these proxypass commands inside the virtual host files of your "sites" in: `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites/`

In config files such as: `0000_127.0.0.1_34543_.conf`

I did also read that any customisation for web apps running on MacOS Server should be made to the plist file for the required web app in: `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/webapps/`

In a plist file such as: `com.apple.webapp.wsgi.plist`

Anyway...

I edited the `0000_127.0.0.1_34543_.conf` file adding:

```
ProxyPass /chat/stream/ ws://localhost:8001/
ProxyPassReverse /chat/stream/ ws://localhost:8001/
```

Eager to test out my first web socket chat connection I refreshed the page only to see an error printed in the apache log:

```
No protocol handler was valid for the URL /chat/stream/. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

I had read of many people finding a solution at least with Apache on Ubuntu or a custom install on MacOS.
I even tried installing Apache using Brew and when that didn't work I almost proceeded to install `nginx`.

After countless hours/days of googling I reached to the Apache mailing list for some help with this error. Yann Ylavic was very generous with his time and offered me various ideas on how to get it going. After trying the following:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/chat/stream/ is_websocket
RequestHeader set Upgrade WebSocket env=is_websocket
ProxyPass /chat/stream/ ws://myserver.local:8001/chat/stream/
```

I noticed that the interface server on port 8001 Daphne was starting to receive ws connections!
However in the client browser it was logging:

```
"Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Upgrade' header is missing"
```

From what I could see `mod_dumpio` was logging that the `"Connection: Upgrade"` and `"Upgrade: WebSocket"` headers were being sent as part of the web socket handshake:

```
mod_dumpio:  dumpio_in (data-HEAP): HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\nServer: AutobahnPython/0.17.1\r\nUpgrade: WebSocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: 17WYrMeMS8a4ImHpU0gS3/k0+Cg=\r\n\r\n
mod_dumpio.c(164): [client 127.0.0.1:63944] mod_dumpio: dumpio_out
mod_dumpio.c(58): [client 127.0.0.1:63944] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-TRANSIENT): 160 bytes
mod_dumpio.c(100): [client 127.0.0.1:63944] mod_dumpio:  dumpio_out (data-TRANSIENT): HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\nServer: AutobahnPython/0.17.1\r\nUpgrade: WebSocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: 17WYrMeMS8a4ImHpU0gS3/k0+Cg=\r\n\r\n
```

However the client browser showed nothing in the response headers.

I was more stumped than ever.

I explored the client side jQuery framework as well as the  the Django channels & autobahn module to see if perhaps something was amiss, and then revised my own app and various combinations of suggestions about Apache and it's module. But nothing stood out to me.

​Then I reread the ReadMe.txt inside the apache2 dir: `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/ReadMe.txt`

> "​Special notes about the web proxy architecture in Server application
>   5.0:
>
> This version of Server application contains a revised architecture for all HTTP-based services. In previous versions there was a single instance of `httpd` acting as a reverse proxy for Wiki, Profile, and Calendar/Address services, and also acting as the Websites service.​​ With this version, there is a major change: A single instance of `httpd` runs as a reverse proxy, called the `Service Proxy`, and several additional instances of `httpd` run behind that proxy to support specific HTTP-based services, including an instance for the Websites service.
>
> Since the `httpd` instance for the Websites service is now behind a reverse proxy, or `Service Proxy`, note the following: ​...  It is only the external `Service Proxy httpd` instance that listens on TCP ports `80` and `443`; it proxies HTTP requests and responses to Websites and other HTTP-based services. ​... ​"​

​I wondered if thus ServiceProxy had somet​hing to do with it. I had a look over: `/Library/Server/Web/Config/Proxy/apache_serviceproxy.conf`
and noticed a comment - `"# The user websites, and webdav"​`.

I figured it wouldn't hurt to try adding the `proxypass` definitions & `rewrite` rules that people had suggested on the forums as their solution.

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8001/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8001/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:8001%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

**​Sure enough after restarting the `ServiceProxy` it all started to work!​**

Adam

Comment: Guy... you rock!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the ReadMe.txt file in /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/

It writes about the new proxy service where requests first go to an http server running on port 80 and 443, which are then forwarded to internal ports 34580 and 34543.

For the wstunnel module there's a conflict with the mod proxy module, where mod proxy will strip out tunnel headers (https://lists.gt.net/apache/users/393509). I confirmed this by changing the LogFormat in apache_serviceproxy.conf by adding to LogFormat

```
c:\"%{Connection}i\" u:\"%{Upgrade}i\"
```

I did the same in httpd_server_app.conf and could see the Connection and Upgrade websocket headers were being removed before getting to my webapp.

The fix was merely to add a file in /Library/Server/Web/Config/Proxy for my application. Look at the last line in apache_serviceproxy.conf to see the expected naming format. In my case the file is called apache_serviceproxy_customsites_ws.conf

The contents:

```
ProxyPass /ws/ ws://localhost:34543/ws/
ProxyPassReverse /ws/ ws://localhost:34543/ws/
```

This will forward the ws request to the expected internal https port 34543 and retain the headers. You must forward it to 34543 or 34580. And also note the path is included so that it can be picked up in the next step.

Then, in my webapp_script (the include file for my webapp) I have:

```
ProxyPass "/ws/"  "ws://localhost:61614/"
ProxyPassReverse "/ws/"  "ws://localhost:61614/"
```

This forwards the request to my websocket server running on port 61614.

With that, it's now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what [@adamteale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/668846/adamteale) mentioned in his answer (the TL;DR) version, I also had to add

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

in my apache virtual host config. Without this, Daphne wasn't returning back any response. Perhaps it was, but it wasn't being sent back to the client.

The only other unresolved issue for my setup is that daphne isn't handling `wss` connection. Either Apache isn't terminating SSL for `wss` or something else is happening. It does terminate SSL for all other `http` requests. However, that question is for another thread. I will raise it as soon as I am done with more research on it.

*Note*: Couldn't add comments to Adam's answer due to MyCurrentRep < 50